# Find different values of the same key in a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have to write a function `get_left_overlaps` that must return a sorted list of integers of a certain key, which is  ''Read''.

```
overlaps = {'Read1': {'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read5': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 29}, 
'Read3': {'Read1': 0, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1, 'Read6': 1}, 
'Read2': {'Read1': 13, 'Read3': 1, 'Read5': 21, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 0}, 
'Read5': {'Read1': 39, 'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 14}, '
'Read4': {'Read1': 1, 'Read3': 1, 'Read2': 17, 'Read5': 2,'Read6': 0},
'Read6': {'Read1': 0, 'Read3': 43, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1}}
```

**desired output:**

```
get_left_overlaps(overlaps, 'Read1')

[0,0,1,13,39]
```

How can I modify the code below in order to get the desired output?

```
keys = set()
def get_left_overlaps():
    for key,val in overlaps[0].items():
        for item in overlaps[1:]:
            if overlaps[key] == val:
                keys.add(key)
```

Comment: Why 0 is twice in the output?

Comment: For best results, demonstrate an attempt to solve the problem, share what you tried, and why it's not suitable.

Comment: You call the method with arguments. The method accepts none

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 loops, need to iterate on the 2-level dict you have, then compare the inner key to a given value, and store the integer value is that's correct

```
def get_left_overlaps(data, search_item):
    keys = []
    for key, values in data.items():
        for val, nb in values.items():
            if val == search_item:
                keys.append(nb)
    return sorted(keys)



overlaps = {'Read1': {'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read5': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 29},
            'Read3': {'Read1': 0, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1, 'Read6': 1},
            'Read2': {'Read1': 13, 'Read3': 1, 'Read5': 21, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 0},
            'Read5': {'Read1': 39, 'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 14},
            'Read4': {'Read1': 1, 'Read3': 1, 'Read2': 17, 'Read5': 2, 'Read6': 0},
            'Read6': {'Read1': 0, 'Read3': 43, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1}}

print(get_left_overlaps(overlaps, 'Read1'))  # [0, 0, 1, 13, 39]
print(get_left_overlaps(overlaps, 'Read2'))  # [0, 0, 1, 1, 17]
print(get_left_overlaps(overlaps, 'Read4'))  # [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```